# GitLab CI/CD: How to deploy app with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm a total newbie when it comes to CI/CD, so I'm asking your pardon in advance for not using the right terms/doing stupid things.

I have a docker-compose file which I can use to start my application with `sudo docker-compose up -d`. Works fine locally, but I also have a remote Virtual Machine, which I want to use to test my application.

I want to run some tests (I will implement them later on) and deploy the app if everything is ok with every push to my repoistory. I looked into the docs, installed gitlab-runner, and tried this for a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"


deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Restaring containers.."
    - cd /path/too/app/repo
    - git pull
    - sudo docker-compose down && sudo docker-compose up -d
```

However, when I tried the docker runner, it gave me an error saying it could not find the path to the directory. I understand that this is caused by the fact that it runs every stage in a separate container. How can I restart my application containers (preferably with compose) on the VM? Is there a better approach to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I'm currently trying to achieve something similar. Maybe this tutorial helps you as well: https://medium.com/@vitalypanukhin/docker-compose-and-gitlab-b209d09210f6